# Binding datagrid combobox to object not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm using .NET 3.5 and the WPF Toolkit for the DataGrid control. I want the datagrid to show a collection of items, and a combobox column to show one item from a collection. I'm probably doing something wrong with the binding, but when I run it the combobox column is blank, however I can select an item from the combo box and it then shows this. Any help much appreciated, thanks!

My XAML:

```
    <tk:DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            <tk:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="MyComboBox" Header="Member" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MyMember}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
```

My code:

```
class Member
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + " - " + Name;
    }
}

class Data
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Member MyMember { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var list = new List<Member>()
        {
            new Member() { Id = "01", Name = "aaa" },
            new Member() { Id = "02", Name = "bbb" },
            new Member() { Id = "03", Name = "ccc" }
        };

        MyComboBox.ItemsSource = list;

        var datalist = new List<Data>()
        {
            new Data() { Description = "abc", MyMember = new Member() { Id = "01", Name = "aaa" } },
            new Data() { Description = "def", MyMember = new Member() { Id = "02", Name = "bbb" } },
            new Data() { Description = "ghi", MyMember = new Member() { Id = "03", Name = "ccc" } }
        };

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = datalist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var list = new List<Member>()
    {
        new Member() { Id = "01", Name = "aaa" },
        new Member() { Id = "02", Name = "bbb" },
        new Member() { Id = "03", Name = "ccc" }
    };
        **Member _me = new Member() { Id = "04", Name = "ddd" };
        list.Add(_me);**
        MyComboBox.ItemsSource = list;

        var datalist = new List<Data>()
    {
        new Data() { Description = "abc", **MyMember = _me** },
        new Data() { Description = "def", MyMember = new Member() { Id = "02", Name = "bbb" } },
        new Data() { Description = "ghi", MyMember = new Member() { Id = "03", Name = "ccc" } }
    };

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = datalist;
```

Made little changes in adding item to the list. the items added vs the assigning the selected item is not same.

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed it by implementing IEquatable on the Member class.